# JQuery unbind anonymous function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

I have a function like this:

```
function init() {
    $('#someElement').unbind('change', init);
    $('#someElement').chosen().change(function () {
        init();
    } 
}
```

But `unbind` is not working for `second execution` and `duplicate` event listeners.

But `$('#someElement').unbind()` works as expected.

> Answer: I find the right way,it's a simple:
>
> need to use:
>
> ```
> function init() {
>     $('#someElement').one('change', function() {
>        init;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: You should bind it using ref method: `$('#someElement').chosen().change(init);`  (or unbind it using anonymous function...)

Answer (score 3):

You're providing an anonymous function to the `change` event, hence passing the reference of `init()` on unbind does not work.

To get this to work as you require, pass the reference of `init()` when attaching the event:

```
function init() {
    $('#someElement').unbind('change', init).chosen().change(init); 
}
```

Note that this unbind/bind pattern seems a little redundant. You should look in to delegated event handlers instead as they may suit your needs better.

Also note that `unbind()` is considered outdated and you should use `off()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but does not work. I found answer and add in my topic message